# Ethereum account for HD Wallet key generated with xpub key only using bitcoinj

Tags: web3j, public-key, java, hd-wallets, bip32

Accordingly to the BIP32/BIP44 specification recommendations I generating HD Wallet addresses using `bitcoinj` library (`DeterministicKey` instances) with the path like M/44'/60'/0'/0/0 using xpub key only (non-hardened keys can derive child public key without knowing private keys) to use them later for funds receiving operations only. But I was unable to get corresponding Ethereum address using web3j library, as I getting "Private key bytes not available" error (that is of course true).

My code sample for the address generation:

```
String xpub = "xpub6Df54KC7ti7yvkfDAwsL4QJ1a69GeMM1ChaNqSnGzbpFdxd4PCy1FzdPVftoBYFA4ogmvDUccUbEhGsozE1YkXtQ2YMxAXWKcM8cBxYD6cp";
DeterministicKey extKey = DeterministicKey.deserializeB58(xpub,mainnetParams);
DeterministicKey addrKey = HDKeyDerivation.deriveChildKey(extKey,0);
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(addrKey.getPrivateKeyAsHex());
System.out.println(credentials.getAddress());
```

returned keys fully corresponds to the https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ results. The error raises on the `addrKey.getPrivateKeyAsHex()` call.

Also I tried another way:

```
System.out.println("address from pub=" + Keys.getAddress(addrKey.getPublicKeyAsHex()));
```

but in this case the result does not look correct accordingly to https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Is it possible at all to generate Ethereum address without private key?

Any advice/explanation/link highly appreciated.